# What are the various steps to contribute my own module to Drupal.org?

Tags: 7, community-official-site

I wrote a custom javascript thing for the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module but I'm not sure how to go about publishing this on drupal.org.

I know there are a lot of requirements, but what are the steps to be completed and where to publish (contribute) this module?

It seems daunting since I never contributed a module before.

Comment: Should you open a new project? Or maybe it's easier to add it to an existing project? The [Drupal Ladder](http://drupalladder.org/ladder/ee503327-50be-1904-8d04-9499098cad64) project will be extremely helpful as it contains step by step tutorials on involvement on the drupal community and adding code to existing projects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main pages you need to read are [Best practices for creating and maintaining projects](http://drupal.org/node/7765) and [Project application checklist](http://drupal.org/node/1587704).  If you have never done this before, you need to read [Creating a sandbox (experimental) project](http://drupal.org/node/1011196)

In short, you need to

- Obtain git access on drupal.org
- Create your sandbox project
- Commit your code
- Submit it for review
- If approved, it will be promoted to be a full project

Keep in mind that your project will likely never be officially reviewed unless you get a [review bonus](http://drupal.org/node/1410826).  Participating in other reviews is also a good way to learn about best practices so you can get through the initial review smoothly.

Comment: Please make sure to run everything through ventral before trying to publish it - http://ventral.org/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for most of the steps in the procedure described in the first answer, is to find an existing project (namespace) that is obsolete, unsupported or looking for a new maintainer.

After you found a project that might fit (e.g. with a relevant namespace), the process to become the new maintainer typically takes between a few hours and about 2 weeks at max.

For way more details on that, refer to my answer to 
"[Are there any alternatives to applying for a full project on drupal.org?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/111)".